# Iterating over a JavaScript object to bind keys

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Considering the following code:

```
controls = {
  'w': 'up',
  's': 'down',
  'a': 'left',
  'd': 'right'
};

keysPressed = [];

for (control in controls) {
  direction = controls[control];
  $(document).bind('keydown', control, function() {
    keysPressed.push(direction);
  });
}
```

Only the `right` direction gets bound, and it is bound to all four keys. This is obviously not intended, but what am I missing about JavaScript that prevents all the properties from being bound appropriately?

**EDIT:**

For clarification, I'm using [jQuery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) to handle key names. And this is a snippet; you can assume all variables have been declared. Also, code is in a safety `function` wrapper.

**SOLUTION:**

I solved it with this modification:

```
controls = {
  'w': 'up',
  's': 'down',
  'a': 'left',
  'd': 'right'
};

keysPressed = [];

addToKeyPressArray = function(value) {
  return function() {
    keysPressed.push(value);
  };
};

removeFromKeyPressArray = function(value) {
  return function() {
    keysPressed = keysPressed.filter(value);
  };
};

for (control in controls) {
  direction = controls[control];
  $(document).bind('keydown', control, addToKeyPressArray(direction));
  $(document).bind('keyup', control, removeFromKeyPressArray(direction));
}
```

That's an odd JavaScript quirk.

Comment: All those variables are declared somewhere above, right?

Comment: The second argument of `bind()` should be an object (representing event data), not a string.

Comment: I don't understand why you're binding four keydown handlers...

Comment: @Šime This is for a 2D game I'm designing. The player may only move in one direction at a time, so I'm pushing directions to the array, and the last element is polled for the current direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like it's probably the basic "closure in for loop" issue that many people trip up on with JS.

An explanation and solution is easy to find via google, here's one for example: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: Yep, this did it. Good explanation of an interesting JavaScript quirk. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$( document ).keypress( function ( e ) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode( e.keyCode );

    if ( controls[ char ] ) {
        keysPressed.push( controls[ char ] );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the `direction` variable (using `var`), so it will be in global scope. This means the for-loop will run and then `direction` will be set to `right`.

All keys are bound, but all call

```
keysPressed.push(direction);
// and that is:
keysPressed.push("right");
```

Also I recommend to read Jani's post (and the related article) as you could have walked into that issue as well.